# How to make a post request to a PHP server

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart, post

I know this is a duplicate question but I still need help with my code.

When I make a post request with postman it succeeds but when I use the flutter code it fails.

Any idea why?

So this is the flutter code to make the post request:

```dart
Future createQuote() async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('http://<myserver.com>/quotes/post.php'),
      body: json.encode(
        {
          'quot': _quoteController.text,
          'teller': _tellerController.text,
        },
      ),
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200 && response.body == 'success') {
      print('s: ' + response.body);
      // Navigator.pop(context);
    } else {
      print(response.body);
      var test = jsonEncode(
        {
          'quot': _quoteController.text,
          'teller': _tellerController.text,
        },
      );
      print(test);
      // throw Exception('Failed to create quote');
    }
  }
```

And this is the php file:

```php
require_once('db.php');
$stm = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO quots (quot, teller) VALUES (:quot, :teller)");
$stm->bindParam(':quot', $_POST['quot']);
$stm->bindParam(':teller', $_POST['teller']);

$quot = $_POST['quot'];
$teller = $_POST['teller'];
if ($stm->execute()) {
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "failure: ". $_POST['quot'] . $teller;
};
```

Comment: do you get any response in console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to `jsonEncode` the post body, use it as a plain `Map`.

```dart
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('http://<myserver.com>/quotes/post.php'),
      body: 
        {
          'quot': _quoteController.text,
          'teller': _tellerController.text,
        },
    );
```